# Asus A52F Laptop Hanigng on BIOS

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bios, freeze, asus-laptop

The laptop first showed a problem about 'no bootable media', so I tried going into system restore. It was very slow and once I tried system restore it hung on a blank screen with the windows 7 login background. I waited an hour, then I gave up and hard rebooted it(I assumed it just wasn't doing anything). I then restarted it and it showed up with the same message. Thinking I could still salvage the hard drive's contents, and that it was a problem with the OS, I inserted a Ubuntu live CD, tried going into the hard drive contents, but I was greeted with an error message telling me that the hard drive was corrupted, and to run chkdsk on windows. Obviously I  couldn't. However I was able to mount the recovery partion, or the D:\, from Ubuntu. I restarted, and I end up here. The Computer is hanging at the BIOS. I leave it 2 hours, nothing. I'm really confused and am starting to run out of Ideas. I am now beginning to assume it is a hard drive problem. Any ideas would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the drive entirely and see if it still hangs.

Comment: It got past the BIOS this time.(With the hard drive removed). Do you think I will be able to salvage any data from it?

Comment: It may just have needed reseating, so try putting it back.  If it still acts up I'd give it 90% odds that the problem is the drive itself though.

Comment: No luck. I also tried replacing the memory but no luck again. Any last ideas?

Comment: I think it's a safe bet that there's the problem...unless you have another drive you can try.